# DIY small light pipe

Tags: led, light-guide

I need a small (3 cm), 90° angled lightpipe to redirect a 0.5cm LED.

I'm looking for a DIY solution using common materials I already have at home. (Even if it won't redirect all the light it is still OK).

Comment: What DIY materials are we talking?

Comment: There are physical constraints relating the radius of curvature and the pipe diameter to whether it would conduct light.  I can't track them down now, but recall being disappointed in the past!

Comment: Or you know, just replace the led with a 3mm one. or move the led with some wire and glue...

Comment: Try hot glue, according to my boss its wonderful for light piping and it's easy to find

Answer (score 2):

Whatever material you use, the rule of thumb is that the bend radius should be no smaller than 15 times the fiber diameter to avoid loss of light.  My experience is that loss is pretty big when you bend too far.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wGaJMVQt7qc

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing what common materials you have at home, I'd say use nylon monofilament fishing line, or clear weed-whacker string, or a nylon guitar string.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you have available, clear acrylic will give you a solid lightpipe while clear tubing can work reasonably well. Either reflecting the light down the tube, or get thick-walled tubing and cut a solid section to use total internal reflection for the piping.

Answer (score 1):

Dollar store for a piece of suitable plexiglass. cut into a triangle with flat instead of pointy end points. Use a nail file to shape until light is acceptable. A piece of foil covering the sides the light shouldn't escape from helps reflect more of it.

Otherwise, dollar store for a optical fiber toy.

Hot glue sticks, either as is, cut down, or melted into shape using a small mold.

Comment: Cd cases tend too brittle, but see through dvd cases or plastic picture frame front glass works great.